# Tensorflow: Extract Every Other Element

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a time-series (represented as a tensor) with a shape of `[Batch_Size, T, 40]`. Now, I would like to extract every other vector in the sequence starting from timestep 0, and extending to 2, 4, ..., thus yielding something of size `[Batch_Size, T/2, 40]`.

What is the most efficient/fastest way to do this in TensorFlow ? Note that `T` is fixed and known if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slice notation and specify a step of 2 on the second axis you need to extract/sample:

```
t[:,::2]
```

---

*Example*:

```
import tensorflow as tf
​
t = tf.reshape(tf.range(24), (2,6,2))
​
sess = tf.Session()
print('original: \n', sess.run(t), '\n')
print('every other: \n', sess.run(t[:,::2]))
original: 
 [[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]
  [18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]]] 

every other: 
 [[[ 0  1]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 8  9]]

 [[12 13]
  [16 17]
  [20 21]]]
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without running a session?

Comment: @Xitcod13 Not sure the context of your question, but could do something like `sess = tf.InteractiveSession(); <your code>; sess.close()`, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession